# Unable to retrieve result from web service

Tags: android

Why I am unable to get result from web service? When I debug the code, it's showing an exception.

The following code is for the web service request.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected boolean UserNameAvailability(final String sUserName)
{   
    boolean result = false;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(getResources().getString(R.string.targetnamespace), getResources().getString(R.string.usernameavailabilitymethod));
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    PropertyInfo piUserName = new PropertyInfo();
    piUserName.name = "UserName";

    request.addProperty(piUserName, sUserName);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(getResources().getString(R.string.webserviceurl));                 
        try {
            httpTransport.debug =true;
            httpTransport.call(getResources().getString(R.string.usernameavailabilitysoapaction), envelope);                    
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); 
            if (!response.toString().equals("false")) {
                result = true;

            }
            //else
            //{
           //   alertBox("User Name already exists.Please enter different username.");
           // }

          }catch (Exception exception) {
              Log.w("UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity", "Error message is "+exception.getMessage(), exception);
          }


          return result;
}
```

Log cat details

```
    01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-16 18:02:01.956: W/UserNameAvailability - RegisterActivity(241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 18:13:43.946: I/ActivityManager(51): Displayed activity com.anb.eCalculator/.LoginActivity: 1988 ms (total 1988 ms)
01-16 18:13:45.996: I/ActivityManager(51): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.anb.eCalculator/.RegisterActivity }
01-16 18:13:56.002: W/ActivityManager(51): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
01-16 18:13:56.073: W/ActivityManager(51): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44d9f420 com.anb.eCalculator/.RegisterActivity}
01-16 18:14:00.764: I/ActivityManager(51): Displayed activity com.anb.eCalculator/.RegisterActivity: 14756 ms (total 14756 ms)
01-16 18:14:16.317: W/KeyCharacterMap(241): No keyboard for id 0
01-16 18:14:16.317: W/KeyCharacterMap(241): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-16 18:14:18.587: D/ViewFlipper(91): updateRunning() mVisible=true, mStarted=false, mUserPresent=true, mRunning=false
01-16 18:14:18.587: D/ViewFlipper(91): updateRunning() mVisible=true, mStarted=false, mUserPresent=true, mRunning=false
```

Comment: I am unable to get the result from web service. I am new to android development. I doubt that i have wrong code for web service request. Anyone plz guide me.

Comment: what exception you are getting post the Logcat output.

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

@Prakash check out the code below which call web service from activity

```
public class FirstAppUI extends Activity 
{

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "test.org";
    private static final String URL = 
    "http://localhost:8080/AndriodBackend/services/listServices/server-config.wsdd";    
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "Test";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "rate";

     private static final String[] sampleACTV = new String[] {"android", "iphone", blackberry"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, sampleACTV);

        AutoCompleteTextView ACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById
                        (R.id.AutoCompleteTextView01);
        ACTV.setAdapter(arrAdapter);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {   
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            ACTV.setHint("Received :" + resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i hope it will be helpful for you.if its helpful then please accept the ans.

Comment: It looks different... can you plz help me in editing my code for getting the right result...

Answer (score 0):

```
 SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); 

 if (!response.toString().equals("false")) 
       result = true;
```

Try to use the following it might solve your problem.

```
 SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

 String resultString = resultRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
```

resultString you will get result either true or false.

Comment: Can we get the result in boolean?

Comment: once you got result from server you can set the boolean flag depends on your condition. as far as i understand your problem if result from server is false you can set flag to true else you can set flag false.

Comment: Ok.. Can u plz guide me. How to get the value in click event?